# How can I select a string spinner and convert it into an Integer

Tags: android-studio

I was making a android app, I want the user to click to spinner to select the category that has "General", "Important", and "Urgent". Then, I want to convert their choice into an integer something like

```
IF (category=="General"){
    choice=1;
}
```

but turns out my app keep on crashing when i run it, heres my code.

```
package com.example.to_do_app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class DialogActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private int catechoice;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

        Spinner category= findViewById(R.id.taskcate);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> cateadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.category, R.layout.spinner_item);
                cateadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                category.setAdapter(cateadapter);
                category.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String text= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        if (text == "General"){
            catechoice=0;
        }
        else if (text=="Important"){
            catechoice=1;
        }
        else if (text=="Urgent"){
            catechoice=2;
        }
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),catechoice,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Post your logcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this code

```
Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), catechoice, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

with this code

```
Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), String.valueOf(catechoice), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

for check string use equal . change this
text == "General" to text.equal( "General")
and I prefer you create enum and use switch like this

```
public enum Category {

General, Important,Urgent
```

}

and use this method

```
  private int categoryChecker(String text) {

    switch (Category.valueOf(text)) {

        case General:
            return 0;

        case Important:
            return 1;

        case Urgent:
            return 2;

        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + text);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well it do works now but it only toast "0" whenever i set any category in it

Comment: oh im forgot, 
for check string use equal  .  change this text == "General" to text.equal( "General")
and I prefer you create enum and use switch like this 
public enum Category {
    General, Important,Urgent
}
//
  private int categoryChecker(String text) {

        switch (Category.valueOf(text)) {

            case General:
                return 0;

            case Important:
                return 1;

            case Urgent:
                return 2;

            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + text);
        }
  }